Prove $\exists z\in \mathbb{R} \,\forall x \in\mathbb{R}^+ \,\left[ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}\, (y - x = \frac{y}{x}) \leftrightarrow x \neq z \right]$
My solution:
(->) Let $z$ be 1. I will prove by contradiction by letting $z=x$. Given $y-x=y/x$, it follows that $y=x^2/(x-1)$. If $x=1$, the statement $y=x^2/(x-1)$ does not exists, hence a contradiction, so it can be concluded that $x$ is not equal to $z $.
(<-) Let $z$ be 1, since it is given that x is not equal to z, it can be concluded that $y=x^2/(x-1)$.
Is my prove correct? I am having a hard time proving/understanding (<-), I feel like i am just assuming the goal $y=x^2/(x-1)$ is right without any justification on how i go from $x$ to $y=x^2/(x-1)$

$y - x = \frac{y}{x}$ gives $xy-x^{2}=y$ or $y(x-1)=x^{2}$. So $y=\frac {x^{2}}{x-1}$.

Your proof is technically right, however, it's quite unstructured and unorthodox the way you've written it.

@Vaskara_GRek_O Could you elaborate? Thanks.

@Darren I can only assume that you're just starting to understand proof writing, so my advice is for you to practice and read more proofs. You'll eventually get the hang of it.

I second @Vaskara_GRek_O's comment. Your "technically right" proof can be rewritten in the following more "structured and orthodox way".
First of all (as you partially justified): for any real number $x$, the existence a real number $y$ such that $y-x=\frac yx$ is equivalent to $x\ne1$:

if $x\ne1$ then $y:=\frac{x^2}{x-1}$ does the job, and
if $x=1$ there is no solution $y$, i.e. $\forall y\in\Bbb R\quad y-1\ne \frac y1$.

This remark leads naturally to the (unique possible) choice for $z$.
Let $z$ be $1$. Then, for every $x\in\Bbb R^+$ (and even for every $x\in\Bbb R$):
$$x\ne1\leftrightarrow x \neq z.$$
Equivalently (by the initial remark)
$$\left[\exists y \in \mathbb{R}\, \left(y - x = \frac{y}{x}\right) \right]\leftrightarrow x \neq z,$$
q.e.d.
